# Chrome displays strange color issues

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

I support a web page that's been live for a long time. Recently a few users have mentioned the page is displaying with odd colors when using Chrome. Below is the page rendered in Chrome on a few computers. Most computers are displaying correctly. (all computers are using the latest Chrome version)

[image]

Chrome displaying correctly:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Any idea why a few chrome browsers are rendering wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps for me: go to chrome://flags and switch GPU rasterization property to Disabled

Comment: This resolved the issue, but the question remains why? A website that hasn't changed has the issue with an up today version of Chrome, suddenly has an issue on a few computers.

Comment: My similar issue visible both on work (with integrated Intel videocard) and home computer (with dedicated Nvidia), so, I think, it is not a driver bug. Looks like a Chrome bug, visible in some configuration

Comment: Its a bug on chrome because previous versions did not suffer this, and after i updated, it started to display those render issues.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this go to chrome://flags and go to "Color correct rendering" and disable

Comment: i wont tell that to my clients ... HAHA

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work. Still puzzled.

Comment: two days looking for a solution - it was so simple like this

Comment: @RicardoSantos This is not the solution, because our clientes wont be changing this flag... its a workaround for developers perhaps. But will disable other feature?

Answer (score 1):

Also try setting `Force color profile` to `sRGB` in `chrome://flags`